# How to dismiss modalView tapping outside of the modal view

Tags: swift, segue, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a segue which type is modal,and I set its presentationstyle to formsheet.

[image]

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

When I tap the dimmed view, the "popover" view doesn't dimiss itself.Is there any trick to dimiss itself when tapping outside of the modal view?

Comment: I think that's just the nature of the `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. From the docs "All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them."

Comment: I guess the idea is that the FormSheet is generally used to present a fairly involved view that you don't want disappearing by accident.

Comment: I just mix that with PopoverController,which can be dismissed by tapping outside of the visible view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by using `UIPopoverController` class and `modalInPopover` property in `UIViewController`.Setting `modalInPopover` to true causes an owning popover controller to disallow interactions outside this view controller while it is displayed.The default value is false.[Here is the full doc.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalInPopover)